# How can I customize template of the Mailboxer email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It automatically delivers email which says

```
You have a new message: subject

      You have received a new message:    


        Body      

      Visit http://example.com/ and go to your inbox for more info
```

Anyone knows how to customize this template?
If possible, I'd like to use i18n for this template form.

Thanks!!
.

Comment: https://github.com/ging/mailboxer#i-need-a-gui

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't look like talking about email template.

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303303/anyone-can-think-of-any-way-to-customize-email-mailboxer-gems-template-view-o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to generate views for the mails that are sent to the user
`rails g mailboxer:views`
this will generate two different folders in `<your rails app>/app`

1- `notification_mailer - containing template files when a notification is sent to a user`

2- `message_mailer - containing template files when a message is sent to a user`

You can change those templates .

Another thing that you can do is to uncomment/add these lines in `/config/initializer/mailboxer.rb`

```
config.notification_mailer = CustomNotificationMailer
config.message_mailer      = CustomMessageMailer
```

and create above two mailers classes which must contain the following function

```
send_email
```

the parameters to this function and their implementation is given on this link . You will get a hint of how to write your own send_mail function .

[Notification Mailer Send Email function](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ging/mailboxer/Mailboxer/NotificationMailer)

[Message Mailer Send Email function](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ging/mailboxer/Mailboxer/MessageMailer)

Comment: The fact that your mailers must contain a function named `send_mail` is important, and does not appear anywhere else on the internet appart from here, seemingly. Thanks.