# Anyone can think of any way to customize Email( Mailboxer gem's) template view on rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm currently using gem called "Mailboxer" on rails3.
Everytime, mailboxer delivers email, and it seems it's using the template shown below.
Anyone knows how to customize this template?

Even though you install mailboxer, views won't be produced so that you can't customize it!

```
You have a new message: subject

      You have received a new message:    


Body
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rails g mailboxer:views
```

Will generate the view files you need so you can edit them.