# How do I customize the Mailboxer email Subject?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mailboxer

I've just installed Mailboxer (`gem 'mailboxer'`) in my Rails 3.1.1 app… I have the email notifications working.

I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199613/how-can-i-customize-template-of-the-mailboxer-email) instructions to customize the notification email that users receive when they are sent a new message via the Mailboxer engine on my app… This allows me to edit the contents of the email message they receive, but I want to change the 'Subject' in the email header from the default "Mailboxer new message:" to a customized subject.

I'm assuming there might be a line I can add to the `mailboxer.rb` config file?!?!?

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I totally missed the obvious on this one... Just need to add a custom mailer, then you have full control.

Add the following to the `mailboxer.rb` config file:

```
Mailboxer.setup do |config|
  config.notification_mailer = CustomNotificationMailer
  config.message_mailer = CustomMessageMailer
 ...
end
```

As clearly noted in the wiki, [here](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer#emails).

Comment: I saw this in the wiki, but I don't like having to create an entirely new class just to change the subject.

Comment: Yeah, I thought there would be an easier variable setting or something... It's not that difficult if you copy the mailer views, do this first: `rails g mailboxes:views`, then you can copy the views that generates into your mailer

Answer (score 9):

just change your en.yml file and set your own subjects:

```
mailboxer.message_mailer.subject_new
mailboxer.message_mailer.subject_reply
```

the "subject" var contains the mailboxer-message subject. Ex:

```
en:
  mailboxer:
    message_mailer:
      subject_new: 'Hey, you receive a new message about %{subject}'
      subject_reply: 'Hey, you receive a new reply about %{subject}'
```

PS: any time you can test the result at console with:

```
I18n.translate("mailboxer.message_mailer.subject_new", :subject => "hello")
```

* just change the "hello" for your actual subject